# how to display an .tif image on RVIZ

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How can I display an .tif image on RVIZ. I want to display a google map image (already downloaded) about the operation scenario.

Thanks in advance

Miguel Pinto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64356/how-to-display-an-.tif-image-on-rviz/) by [MiguelRobPinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2036/miguelrobpinto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure how to directly visualize a .tif image in rviz but a solution that comes into my mind is that you can read image using openCV and publish it on a topic using cv_bridge.

Hope this helps..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0